# Keyboard is not allowing me to finish installation

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

When I am installing ubuntu, it gets to the screen where you set up your username and password, but it won't allow me to click on the boxes and type anything so I can't set up anything and complete the installation

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one of my computers, I had problems with the *normal* keyboard. It would work a bit and then stop working. As if the OS was not accepting events from that serial port. This is a PS/2 port. Once everything is installed, though, the keyboard works just fine at all time.

I have another USB keyboard which is really large so we don't use it otherwise, but using that keyboard worked like a charm. So if you have another keyboard you could try that.

One reason the OS may get confused is that one of the USB port has a tablet. When I installed that other keyboard I disconnected the tablet. Later I thought that may have been the issue. But I had to fix the boot hard drive the other day and disconnected the tablet and rebooted and the keyboard did not work right again.

I don't recall any such problems before 18.04. It's something new.

Comment: Hi there, I tried switching keyboards and it seems to have worked. I don't believe it was able to detect the old keyboard at all, but the new one is working fine between Linux and Windows! Thanks